# Architecture and technologies of an instant chat app in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, websocket, chat

I want to build an instant chat app with flutter without any third party services.

I've been working in a simple app using a restful laravel api for login, multiple methods and logout, using token authentication for each request. However, I find that architecture not suitable for a modern instant chat. I discovered WebSockets, which sound great, but can't yet grasp how I could subscribe to and consume one from flutter. I´ve read about web channels, but I'm not sure how they handle authentication for users. Is it possible to handshake and establish a session from my app? If so, how?

Or, can it be done totally restful? How could I post messages and listen other user's messages in that case?

Besides the chat functionality, is it recommended to work restfully? Or is flutter able to mantain a solid, authenticated session? I'm kinda new in flutter.

I appreciate any info, link or recommendation. Please, refrain if you were going to mention firebase, I want to build my own backend. Thanks!!

Comment: To simplify real-time chat implementation, you could try [QuickBlox Flutter SDK](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/flutter-quick-start) that supports 1-1 chat, group chat and video calls.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out MQTT, an IOT protocol which is currently used for chat applications very widely.

To know about MQTT, [see this](https://zoetrope.io/tech-blog/brief-practical-introduction-mqtt-protocol-and-its-application-iot/).

But first I will recommend you to understand Pub-Sub(Publisher-Subscriber) Model, if you understand it then that's great.

For pub-sub model, [see this](https://aws.amazon.com/pub-sub-messaging/).

> Or, can it be done totally restful? How could I post messages and listen other user's messages in that case?

Yes, it can be done totally restful but honestly it's not recommended. You should do it with websockets.

> Besides the chat functionality, is it recommended to work restfully? Or is flutter able to maintain a solid, authenticated session? I'm kinda new in flutter.

Depends on your architectural choice. There are many good options on which architecture you want to choose. Apart from restful there is GraphQL also, if you are comfortable with it. Apart from chat functionality mostly you will see people using RESTful but people who know GraphQL, might also use that instead of RESTful.